# I am getting a IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed for django

Tags: python, django

I am getting an integrity error for creating a customer here. When the first customer tries to create an account this code works. But when  new customer comes and tries to create a account it give the UNIQUE constraint failed. Where as When a seller tries to create an account it creates it, it works for every new seller. But this codes doesn't seem to work for the customer.

This was the first error.

And I got another error as

**FieldError at /accounts/customer/register/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: active, address, customer, customer_id, email, id, order, timestamp, update**

when I try to save the email of that Customer it gives this error. Since I have a billing model set up and its given in the bottom below.
And this one doesn't work even for the first customer who comes and tries to create an account.

**I used a custom user model**

`accounts models.py`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager() ## This is the new line in the User model. ##


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

**This is the views that I created**

`views - seller.py`

```
def register_page(request):
    form = CreateSellerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateSellerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            group = Group.objects.get(name='seller')
            user.groups.add(group)

            Seller.objects.create(
                user=user,
                email=user.email
            )

            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully!')
            return redirect('accounts:seller-login')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/seller/register.html', context)
```

`views - customer.py`

```
def register_page(request):
    form = CreateCustomerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)

            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user,
                # email=user.email    ### FieldError Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. 
            )


            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully!')
            return redirect('accounts:customer-login')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer/register.html', context)
```

**This is the forms**

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from accounts.models import Seller, User

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Seller
        fields = '__all__'

class CreateCustomerForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

class CreateSellerForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email
```

Here I used a signal to create the billingprofile.

`billing models.py`

```
class BillingProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        guest_email_id = request.session.get('guest_email_id')
        created=False
        obj = None
        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(user=user, email=user.email)
        else:
            pass
        return obj, created

class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

def user_created_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, email=instance.email)

post_save.connect(user_created_receiver, sender=Customer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your signal receiver, you're trying to pass the `Customer` instance to the `user` field which the `BillingProfile` model doesn't have. Pass it to the `customer` field instead:

```
def user_created_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(customer=instance, email=instance.email)
```